# Inline display many to many admin django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Simplified example of my code would be:

in models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class A(models.Model):
    ...

class C(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    b = models.ForeignKey(B, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class B(models.Model):
    a_fields = models.ManyToManyField(A)
```

then in admin.py

```
@admin.register(A)
class AAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

class CInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = C
    extra = 0

@admin.register(B)
class BAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (CInline,)
```

It won't show fields of `A` inline when I open the add new form for `B` entity. It actually shows a drop box with pre-existing entries and allows me to click on '+' to add new `A`, which is not desired behavior plus the same happens without using inline in the first place. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

You can try [that](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models).
Or use **admin.ModelAdmin()** and try filter_horizontal field

Comment: The first link suggests similar approach to one I described, it is just that the django default `through` class is used. After that they describe my situation exactly that I followed, which is why I find it weird that my example is not working as expected. I tried filter_horizontal but it is not quite what I'm looking for since it just changes the select box to a similar interface with a search option.